# Loop through an array with objects

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I get the following array from my back end:

```
[Object { 7="77.105.239.8", 10="77.105.239.11", 18="77.105.239.19", more...}]
```

How can I use ng-options to fill my select dropdown with the Ips from the array?

The array above Is the result of an array_diff from my back end In PHP:

```
foreach($ips as $ip)
                {
                    $taken[] = $ip['ip'];
                }

                $start = (ip2long($serie->net) + 1);
                $antal = pow(2,(32-$serie->mask));

                for($i = $start; $i < ($start+$antal-3); $i++)
                {
                    if(end(explode(".", long2ip($i))) != "0")
                    {
                        $possible_ips[] = long2ip($i);
                    }
                }

                $poss = array_diff($possible_ips, $taken);

                return $poss;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to or cannot fix the data to be formatted like m4lt3 answer, then you need to do some preprocessing of the data before trying to bind it.

```
var originalData = [{ 7: "77.105.239.8", 10: "77.105.239.11", 18: "77.105.239.19"}];
var originalObject = originalData[0];
var newData = [];
for (var i in originalObject) {
  newData.push({'id': i, 'ip': originalObject[i]});
}
$scope.ipList = newData;
```

...then you could bind ipList using `ngOptions`.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to fix this in my backend, but I don't know how to take the values In my $poss variable, and make an correct array of it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting an array with only one field which contains an object with the data you need. 
My suggestion is, to fix that in the backend. So that you get what you need -> a real array. Like this:

```
[
     { "id":7, "ip":"77.105.239.8"},
     { "id":10, "ip":"77.105.239.150"}, 
     { "id":12, "ip":"77.105.239.12"}
]
```

Since array_diff returns an assoziative array, we need to transform it to a non-assoziative array and return it (either with json_encode or not, depending on you set up):

```
...
$poss = array_diff($possible_ips, $taken);
$res = [];
foreach ($poss as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = $value;
}
return json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions how to fix this in my backend?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of data you have, how you receive it and what kind of technology you are using. But generally spoken, you need to create an array of JSON-objects.

Comment: Im using zend framework. I want to take the values from my $poss variable, and make an correct array of It, but I don't know how to do It.

Comment: can you send me the content of this $poss variable, if its a lot just 2 or three parts of it.

Comment: :So no need for me to give you the data In $poss?

Comment: How can I use ng-topions on this? The result of json_encode Is this: ["{"7":"77.105.239.8","10"..."251":"77.105.239.252"}"]

Comment: The problem is, that the array_diff function return an assoziative array, which will be transformed to an object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave your function as is, except change the return statement to: `return json_encode($poss);`